# In my spinner POJO I have id and name. So on button click I want to send my spinner id instead of name in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview, android-spinner

How to Send selected spinner id instead of name in android. Below I am attaching my code. Please refer my code and help me how to send ans supportlisttyperesponse is my api.On button click how to send ISSUETYPEID to post method.

> 

data class SupportListOfIssueResponseArray(

```
@SerializedName("ISSUETYPEID")
var ISSUETYPEID: String? = null,

@SerializedName("ISSUETYPE")
var ISSUETYPE: String? = null
```

)

```
class SupportActivity : BaseActivity() {
 private val TAG: String = SupportActivity::class.java.simpleName
 private var descriptionBox: TextView? = null
 private var issueType: Spinner? = null

 @SuppressLint("ByteOrderMark")
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_support)

   
    descriptionBox = getView(R.id.support_desc)
    issueType = getView(R.id.issue_type_spinner)

     var submitButton = getView<Button>(R.id.submit_button)
    submitButton?.setOnClickListener {
      
        val supportPostRequest = SupportPostRequest()
        supportPostRequest.type = issueType?.selectedItem.toString()
        DashboardService.postSupport(applicationContext, supportPostRequest) {
            if (it != null && it?.error?.errorCode == 0) {
                FGLogger.e(TAG, it?.error.errorCode.toString())
            }
        }

          private fun initIssueTypeSpinner(spinner: AppCompatSpinner) {
          val issueTypes = mutableListOf<String>()


           DashboardService.getListofissues(applicationContext) {
           if (it != null && it?.error?.errorCode == 0) {
            FGLogger.e(TAG, it?.error?.errorCode.toString())
            for (item in it?.response) {
                if (item?.ISSUETYPEID != null) {
                    var Ar = item?.ISSUETYPE.toString()
                    issueTypes.add(Ar)
                 }

             }

         }
           this@SupportActivity?.runOnUiThread({

            val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.fg_bank_account_type_spinner_item, 
            issueTypes)
            spinner.adapter = adapter
        })


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

For passing spinner id you make two array like below

```
val issueTypes = mutableListOf<String>()
val issueTypesID = mutableListOf<Integer>()
```

Than when you add issueTypes array name also add Id in issueTypesID array
now issueTypes array for display name for spinner  and issueTypesID array which get id that id you can used you click button and call api.

Comment: what i need is in dropdown it should show only names ...but on buttonclick it should send only id to api.

Comment: On spinner item click method you can get the position of click item on base of that position you can easy get id like var clickID=isssueTypeID.get(position)  now this clickID pass  on api side.